# Possible to have multiple collections point to same directory?

Tags: jekyll

Is it possible to define multiple collections, but those collections pull their posts from a common directory?

My use case is, I’m creating a website that holds results of professional wrestling events. But there are different “types” of events: televisions shows, pay-per-view events, “house” shows (live, non-broadcast events), etc.

What I’d like to do is to just create all event posts in an **_events** directory, but then define multiple collections for each “type” of event that filters posts based on some criteria (say, category) and then also has its own permalink structure.

Is this possible with Jekyll? I’m looking to do something like:

```yaml
collections:
  ppv:
    directory: _events
    output: true
    permalink: /ppv/:series/:year
    where: "category == 'ppv'"
  tv:
    directory: _events
    output: true
    permalink: /tv/:series/:date
    where: "category == 'tv'"
```

Is this possible? Can I pull posts from a single directory into different collections based on some sort of conditional?